# How to pick first record from the duplicates, With only duplicate column values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is the situation where I have a table in bigquery like following.

[image]

As in the table we have record 1 and 3 with the same id but different first_name (Say the person with the id one changed his first_name) all other fields are same in both of the records (1 and 3) Now I need to select one records out of those 2 how can I do that. I tried self join but that is discarding both of the records, group_by will not work because the records is not duplicate only the Id is duplicate same with the distinct.

Thanks!!!!

The query I am using right now is

```
select * from table t group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use ROW_NUMBER function to assign row numbers to each of your records in the table.

```
select *
from(    
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.id) rn
    from t)
Where rn = 1
```

ROW_NUMBER does not require the ORDER BY clause. Returns the sequential row ordinal (1-based) of each row for each ordered partition. If the ORDER BY clause is unspecified then the result is **non-deterministic**.
If you have record created date or modified dates you can use those in the ORDER BY clause to alway pick up the latest records.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first row unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Let me assume you have such a column.

If you want a particular row, you can use aggregation with an `order by`:

```
select array_agg(t order by ? asc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from t
group by id;
```

`?` is the column that specifies the ordering.

You can also leave out the `order by`:

```
select array_agg(t limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: But i don't have such column to define ordering

Comment: not working as expected while using the second query giving Column id contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY. And if i remove this group by condition it will give me only 1 row as a output which is not what i wanted.

Comment: @RamanMishra . . . That error doesn't make sense.  `array_agg()` *is* an aggregation function.

Comment: please go through this it is an agg function.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg
Thanks! anyways

Comment: @RamanMishra . . . This works.  I have used this construct multiple times in BigQuery.